# Why light scattered in a direction at right angles to the incident light always plane-polarised?

Tags: waves

In my textbook, it is written that polarisation of light occurs by scattering. When light is incident on small particles of dust, air molecules, etc. it is absorbed and re-radiated by the electrons. But why is light plane polarised if unpolarized light falling on the particles is scattered at right angles to it? Why? Can someone please explain. I am so confused.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Ralyeigh scattering induces small dipoles in the molecule (scatterer). These dipoles re-emit light (which is the scatteted light).

The key to your question is now the phase function of Rayleigh scattering, which is according to the above mentioned dipoles donut-shaped. So only the component of the electric field perpendicular to the scattering plane will emit at right angles to the incident direction. The component of $E$ oscillating in the scattering plane cannot emit in $90^\circ$ scattering angle, because this is the axis along which the electrons (dipole) oscillate and there is no emission in the direction of the $z$-axis (donut shape).

As result, the light scattered at right angles from the incident direction is linearly polarized.

Comment: Could you explain in simpler words? Actually I am just a Grade 12 student and I don't know much high stuff physics.

Comment: @Ripan Baruah Think of the scattering molecule like a small antenna. Antennas cannot emit in the direction they are pointing.